# Is text in a link crawable

Tags: seo, html, hyperlink

I have a product box that is encapsulated in a hyperlink so that the entire box is clickable. Within this box I have text about the product (e.g. product name, price, etc). However, as the text is within the link box, it is not selectable by hand. Do crawlers see this text when they view the site, or should it be outside of the main link? I'm looking to optimize the SEO.

Previously we had a separate hyperlink for the image and the product name, but in order to reduce the number of links on the page we encapsulated everything in a single link. An example of the new form is below:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/prod/1 target="_blank">
    <div id="prod1">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/images/prod/1" alt="Prod1"/>
        <h1>The product title<h1>
        <h2>$10.00</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes Google will see it, its valid html5.

Comment: I don't recommend using `<h2>` as the price tag either :) use span.

Comment: From an SEO perspective, what would be the difference?

Comment: none, but its generally bad to use headers straight after another because there's no need. The price isn't a header, its a price that is relevant to H1 so a span with the same styling of the h2 would be better.

Comment: Note that it is possible to select the text by hand ([e.g. on GNU/Linux](http://askubuntu.com/q/282336/82665) by holding *Super* + *Alt*).

Comment: If you want it even cleaner, drop the <div> and put your styling on the <a> instead.

Comment: and before the first "target", make sure the first URL is fully enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The crawler will still see the content encapsulated within the link and index it appropriately as it is valid markup and is standards compliant. As a side note there is no difference between indexing a div with text encapsulated within a link and a simple word or a short number of words encapsulated within a div as the search engine crawlers treat this all the same.

Answer (score -2):

Yes the hyperlink can be crawled by Google search if you add a itemprop="URL"

Comment: What would the `itemprop` do?    I find that Google usually crawls links without it.  Can you add more to your answer about your experience with this, or link to some references?

Comment: Itemprop can label parts of your website like text,links,pictures, ect. This is found in reference to schema markup language that Google understands and creates your search engine results page with. For example if you search my username jehovahsays in Google you will notice the box on the right of the page with my picture and business information. That is created from my schema markup language.